# Performance and Slow Query Users with Breeze

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-breeze

in my laravel site with breeze, when i try to open page, it very very slow. The query is "select * from users where id = 1 limit 1" take 4 seconds.
Why? Can help me? Thanks a lot.

Laravel 9.1, Breeze

[image]

Comment: How many records does your table have? If it has records in thousand then it is normal to take few seconds.

Comment: I have 3 records

Comment: Are you using eloquent?

Comment: If yes then can you post your eloquent query here?

Comment: I think yes! This table created after install breeze in my laravel project

Comment: public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        $model = $this->createModel();

        return $this->newModelQuery($model)
                    ->where($model->getAuthIdentifierName(), $identifier)
                    ->first();
    }

Comment: I don't change anythink, this is breeze standard installation....

Comment: Probably this has nothing to do with the framework, but with your mysql server. Have you tried to run that command in your mysql client?  Here you are how can you test what I´m talking about. https://fedingo.com/how-to-get-query-execution-time-in-mysql/

Comment: Hi, my profiles is  1 | 0.00051821 | select * from users where id = 1 limit 1. This is in the server...in my laravel with breeze 4.2seconds....i don't know why...it absurd....any ideas?